# Are Questions about software design 'too broad' for SO?

Tags: discussion, design, needs-more-focus

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646594/print-formated-invoice-in-c-sharp-application/27647345#27647345) which was shortly thereafter closed as 'too broad' and I wonder why.

I understand that SO is about specific programming problems. But for creating good software its not only important to create good code, use available libraries the correct way, but also to find the best design decisions.

One example: In .Net alone exist at least three different ways to work with XML files. Depending on circumstances/constraints one XML library is the 'best'. If someone needs to decide which library to use she needs some knowledge and experience with each possibilty -or- posts a question on SO.

I think its perfectly legal and useful to post such 'broader' design questions like

- What XML library should i use for...
- What technology should I use to print ...

Opinions? Decisions? Consensus?

Answer (score 4):

The question you refer to has nothing to do with software design. It basically asks "how can I print" which is way too broad.

Stack Overflow is about isolated problems in a codebase. It does not handle larger design decisions nor does it tell you what different libraries or approaches you can use to come to a certain general solution.

The former belongs on [Programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (read the rules of p.se before posting, yada yada) while the latter is offtopic almost everywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Asking for library recommendations is explicitly offtopic:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: For the record, [Software Recommendation.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) can handle appropriately scoped recommendations questions like the OP provided in the examples.  The [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) are very important though.